# How can I uninstall updates to Google Play Services? The buttons are greyed out

Tags: google-play-services, android-device-manager, device-administrator

I'm trying to uninstall updates to the Google Play Services app but the `Force Stop` and `Uninstall updates` buttons are greyed out.

"Android Device Manager" was set as a device administrator but I've unchecked it and it hasn't helped.

Comment: Note that even if you manage to uninstall those updates: they'll be back pretty soon due to its auto-update :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the [Android Device manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm) app installed then this can also make the force stop/uninstall updates buttons be disabled.

If you uninstall the [Android Device manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm) app **and** disable "Android Device Manager" as a device administrator then those options should be enabled.